# How to use KEYGEN html 5 tag in a JSF app?

Tags: html, jsf-2

I want to use the KEYGEN html 5 tag to generate certificates from a Firefox browser.

In my facelet i have a form with the tag and a commandbutton that will submit the form to my backing bean called clientCertificateBean in this case. What I cant figure out is how I get the byteArray public key argument sent by the browser. Can i bind the keygen to a field in my backing bean or send it as an argument in the backing bean method?

```
<h:form>
    <keygen name="RSA public key" challenge="123456789" KEYTYPE="RSA"/>
    <h:commandButton value="Generate" action="#{clientCertificateBean.generate}" />
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems support for keygen will come in JSF 2.2 in the meanwhile i solved it like this:

```
@Named("clientCertificateBean")
public class ClientCertificateBean {

    public void generate() {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        String publicKey = request.getParameter("RSA public key");


    }
```

}

Hope it can help someone.